# ESP32 Restarting

Tags: power-supply, esp32

We see that there are problems with our microcontroller, an ESP323-S3, power supply. The module starts correctly from 4.2 V to 3.3 V. However, when the voltage drops from this value, the microcontroller gives a "brownout" error which indicates that the supply current is not sufficient.

The input voltage goes first through a BOOST ([MP3120](https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/277/MP3120-2945726.pdf)) to 5 V and then through a LDO ([LD1117](https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/389/ld1117-1849389.pdf)) to 3.3 V as you can see in the attached image.

We believe that this problem could be due to the start of some Bluetooth process of the microcontroller which requires a higher current peak than normal. Although in principle this should not create any problem since both the BOOST and the LDO are capable of supplying values above 300 mA.

[image]

Comment: The LD1117 often is too slow to react on RF acitivity in time. You can use a faster regulator or add a 220 uF tantalum capacitor parallel to C22, this worked for me in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply Jens! I'll try what you propose and let you know.

Comment: Jens do you have an approved regulator that does not create this type of problem?

Comment: I have a product, that uses MIC5219-3.3YML with 2 x 47 uF ceramic at a very noisy 6 V input (stepper motor connected) and 22 uF / 6.3 V / X5R  + 100 nF parallel at the output to feed the ESP32. Works with Bluetooth and Wifi.